# remove date and category in WordPress post

Tags: wordpress

I would like to remove creation date and category in WordPress post.

In particular, I would like to use a plugin that hides that infos when I see the list of articles in my home page, or when I read the article (precisely, after the article title)

I do not want to modify Wordpress template files because, after an update, modifications could be lost.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you use a child theme, you can make updates without worrying about updates overwriting them.

Comment: @TaniaRascia I've tried in local modifying something in template files, then I've updated the theme and all modification disappears. I'm using Dazzling free template

Comment: You must create a child theme - this does not mean overwriting your local files. It means copying your files to a new theme, and editing that one. Check if your Dazzling free template has child themes available.

Comment: How can I check if it has a child template available?

Comment: [Here is information about installing your child theme for Dazzling.](https://colorlib.com/wp/forums/topic/dazzling-child-theme/)